# Print contents of array with custom class swift

Tags: swift

I have an array of type custom class as seen below. It has strings, ints, and double values.

```
class TrendData: NSObject {
   var earlyTime = Date()
   var recentTime = Date()
   var earlyTimePrice = Double()
   var recentTimePrice = Double() 
}
```

I have an array as follows

```
let dataArray = [TrendData]()
```

I have filled in 2 values into the dataArray.

Right now when I use a print command as follows

```
print ("Label: \(dataArray)")
```

it prints this `Label: [<App.TrendData: 0x600000472440>] ** [<App.TrendData: 0x600000472440>]`

This is the correct behavior but I want to see all the values within each of these elements in the array. What is the best way to do that? I don't want to explicitly list out each element or even put it into a loop if I can avoid it. I am able to do it, it is just really messy right now. Is there any function or command that does this automatically?

Comment: Just override the `description` method ...

Comment: How would we do that?

Comment: I looked at the post that you said was a duplicate but I wasn't sure exactly how to do that for this specific scenario. really appreciate the help!

Comment: override var description : String {
        return "1: \(earlyTime), 2: \(recentTime)"
    } - would this be right?

Comment: Implement `override var description : String { ... }` to return whatever the representation should be.